# Can I batch aggregations in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have some readonly aggregate pipelines that must be runned in parallel with only one connection available. Is that possible or Mongo allows to only have find, update operations in bulk but not aggregate?

Comment: bulk != parallel. Which language yo are using? Driver should manage a pool of connections.

Comment: bulk is parallel if using unorderedbulk. I can not be creating hundreds of connections per worker, so pool will do nothing

Comment: okay, the short answer - no. bulk ops are for writes, aggregation is read only. The long answer depends on what the actual problem you are facing.

Comment: Thanks. I'm facing perfomance problem. If I'll send 20 requests to MongoDB in one moment, it will took about a second (instead of 50ms) to return all of them because MongoDB runs all commands in the order it receives them from each client connection.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Mongodb driver uses connections pool and executes aggregation commands asynchronously. You don't need to do anything special, apart from ensure your application doesn't wait for responses before executing next query.

Consider a test collection:

```
mgeneratejs '{"num": {"$integer": {"min": 1, "max": 20}}, "text": {"$paragraph": {sentences: 5}}}' -n 100000 | mongoimport -d so -c text
```

a single aggregation query

```
db.text.aggregate([
    {$match: {text: /ert.*duv/i}}, 
    {$group:{_id:null, cnt:{$sum:1}, text:{$push: "$text"}}}
]);
```

takes circa 400 millis.

Running 10 of these in parallel (javascript):

```
const started =  new Date().getTime();
let db;

MongoClient.connect(url, {poolSize: 10})
    .then(cl =>{
        db = cl.db('so');
        return Promise.all([/ert.*duv/i, /kkd.*aql/i, /zop/i, /bdgtter/i, /ppa.*mcm/i, /ert.*duv/i, /kkd.*aql/i, /zop/i, /bdgtter/i, /ppa.*mcm/i]
            .map(regex=>([{$match: {text: regex}}, {$group:{_id:null, cnt:{$sum:1}, text:{$push: "$text"}}}]))
            .map(pipeline=>db.collection('text').aggregate(pipeline).toArray()))
    })
    .then(()=>{db.close(); console.log("ended in " + ( new Date().getTime() - started))});
```

takes 1,883 millis (javascript time), of which ~1,830 are on the db side:

```
db.getCollection('system.profile').find({ns:"so.text", "command.aggregate": "text"}, {ts:1, millis:1})

{
    "millis" : 442,
    "ts" : ISODate("2018-02-22T17:32:39.738Z")
},
{
    "millis" : 452,
    "ts" : ISODate("2018-02-22T17:32:39.747Z")
},
{
    "millis" : 445,
    "ts" : ISODate("2018-02-22T17:32:39.756Z")
},
{
    "millis" : 471,
    "ts" : ISODate("2018-02-22T17:32:39.762Z")
},
{
    "millis" : 448,
    "ts" : ISODate("2018-02-22T17:32:39.771Z")
},
{
    "millis" : 491,
    "ts" : ISODate("2018-02-22T17:32:39.792Z")
},
{
    "millis" : 566,
    "ts" : ISODate("2018-02-22T17:32:39.854Z")
},
{
    "millis" : 561,
    "ts" : ISODate("2018-02-22T17:32:39.856Z")
},
{
    "millis" : 1822,
    "ts" : ISODate("2018-02-22T17:32:41.118Z")
},
{
    "millis" : 1834,
    "ts" : ISODate("2018-02-22T17:32:41.124Z")
}
```

If you do the math you see all 10 started at about same time 2018-02-22T17:32:39.300Z, and [mongostat](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongostat/) indeed shows 10 more connections at the time of script execution.

Limiting `poolSize` to 5 doubles the time, as the requests will be executed in 2 batches of 5.

Driver uses about 1Mb RAM per connection, so 100 connections per worker is not something unreal.

To summarise - ensure you have connections pool configured properly, check number of connections actually used runtime, check you handle requests asynchronously on the application level.